# Odoo v8 not updating modules

Tags: ubuntu, erp, odoo

I have created new module and updated some of base modules. But it is not showing. currently im using Localhost:8069.

on windows i updated the modules on Program Files(x86)/Odoo 8.0-20141014-000207/server/openerp/addons

on Ubuntu i updated /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons

Neither of them updates anything.

*init*.py

```
import daily_transaction.py
```

*openerp*.py

```
{
'name' : 'Daily Transaction Manager',
'version': '1.0',
'author': 'Billy James',
'category': 'Manager',
'complexity': 'easy',
'description': "The Module will manage our daily transaction where we'll keep a log of where and hwat money we have spent on a particular day.",
'depends': [],
'data': [
    'daily_transaction_view.xml',
],
'installable': True,
'auto_install': False,
```

}

daily_transaction.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class daily_transaction(osv.osv):
    _name = "daily_transaction"
    _description = "Daily Transaction"


    _columns = {
        'subject': fields.char('Subject', size=128, required=True),
        'date': fields.date('Date', required=True),
        'note': fields.text('Notes'),
        'amount': fields.float('Amount', required=True),
        'type': fields.selection([
            ('transport', 'Transport'),
            ('household', 'Household'),
            ('personal', 'Personal'),
            ], required=True),

    }
```

i compiled all the py files and found no errors.

Comment: Are those your custom modules?

Comment: Custom Modules and some editing on original modules

Comment: did you edited openerp.py file of that module? if there is any error int that file the module will not show..

Comment: original module is fine now. but adding new module still doesn't show up. does it have to be compiled?

Comment: did you updated your module list?

Comment: Yes, and i just included my codes.

Answer (score 0):

replace openerp.py file with this.

```
{
'name': 'Daily Transaction Manager',
'version': '1.0',
'category' : 'manager',
'author': 'Akhil',
'description': ''' This module records and manages the 
            daily transactions
        ===================================== ''',
'depends': [],
'demo': [],
'data': ['daily_transaction_view.xml'],
'installable': True,
'auto_install': False,
}
```